# Iframe? tring to put dynamic info into a web without leaving it

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have a webpage where i have an aside menu (for navegation between info or widgets, i haven't decided yet) and next to it i have the content info.

well, what i want to get is by clicking links, it triggers an iframe or something for the content.

I mean: i don't want to load another page, i want to stay always in the same, the main page, because i have an audio player, and i don't want it to change a new song every time you load another page.

so, i tried using an iframe, but it doesn't adjust to the content, so if some pages difer in height, then it won't show some, then if others are short, then will be a blank space between the end of the content and the end of the page...

i searched for javascript solution too, but i don't understand it, and cant make it work.

okay, let's say this is the main page, and i want to load nothing, or X webpage at start, thats no problem.

but then when i click in games i want to load another page (that i post after the code of this one) and fit the height.

```css
aside {
  width:15%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

aside > div:not(#marcador) {
  background-color: rgb(40, 44, 47);
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.055);
  color: silver;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: -15px;
  font-family: "Press Start 2P";
  font-size: 0.7em;
  line-height: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

#marcador>ul>li{
  margin-bottom:5px;
}

#marcador li> div {
    font-size: 0.9em;
  opacity: 0;
    display: block;
  
  -moz-transition: opacity 1.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1.2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1.2s ease-in-out;
}

#marcador li:hover > div {
  opacity: 1;
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin-left: 0;
}

#marcador li> div >ul >li {
  max-height: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
#marcador li:hover> div >ul >li {
  max-height: 40px;
  margin-top:5px;
}

#marcador li:hover{
  max-height: 500px !important;
}

#marcador li:hover > a {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

#marcador ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: static;
}

#marcador ul li > a {
  background-color: rgb(40, 44, 47);
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.055);
  color: silver;
  display: block;
  margin-right: -15px;
  font-family: "Press Start 2P";
  font-size: 0.7em;
  line-height: 10px;
  padding: 15px;
  padding-left: 35px;
}

#marcador ul ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

#marcador ul ul a {
  margin-left: 20px;
  background-color: dimgray;
}

#marcador ul ul ul a {
  margin-left: 40px;
  background-color: gray;
  color: black;
}

#marcador img {
  float: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  margin-left: -20px;
}

#marcador li:hover > a > img {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

#marcador a:hover {
  color: orange;
}

#ifrm{
  width:80%;
  display:inline-block;
}

iframe{
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<aside>
                <div id="marcador">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a><img src="Recursos/Select.png"/>INDEX</a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a><img src="Recursos/Select.png"/>Games</a>
                            <div>
                                <ul>

                                    <li>
                                        <a><img src="Recursos/Select.png"/>Sega</a>
                                    </li>

                                    <li>
                                        <a class=ult><img src="Recursos/Select.png"/>Arcade</a>
                                    </li>
                                    
                                    <li>
                                        <a><img src="Recursos/Select.png"/>Nintendo</a>
                                        <div>
                                            <ul>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a><img src="Recursos/Select.png"/>SNES</a>
                                                </li>

                                                <li>
                                                    <a class=ult><img src="Recursos/Select.png"/>NES</a>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                        
                    </ul>
                </div>

    
    
    <div class="example">
              AUDIO PLAYER HERE
                    </div>
                
                
            </aside>
            
            
            
          <div id="ifrm">
    <iframe src="WelcomeInfo.html" frameborder="0"> </iframe>
</div>
```

And by clicking a link in the aside bar then loads this in the iframe

```css
section {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color:beige;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: black;
  display:inline-block;
  width: 100%;

}

article {
  overflow: hidden;
}

article img{
  width: 30%;
  float:right;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section>
                <h1>Lorem cabecera ipsum</h1>
                <article>
                    <figure><img alt="Contruccion" src="Recursos/man-at-work-daisy.svg"/></figure>
                    <p>Ésta página <a href="http://google.es">esta</a> en lorem construcción ipsum, tengan paciencia para ver el final. dejo al lado una señal de construcción por si no ha quedado claro, que hay mucha gente despistada en este mundo</p>

                    <p>
                      
        
                        
                    </p>   
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,     
                    </p>   
                   

                </article>

            </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function a() {
var iframe=document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.setAttribute("id","iframe");
iframe.setAttribute("class","iframe");
iframe.setAttribute("src","page you want")
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
}
```

```html
<div onclick="a()">ShowIframe</div>
```

Comment: i was trying to avoid javascript, and that method just adds another iframe one after another, what i wanted is tho have the info of different sections in different webpages, that shows into the iframe, and change between webpages when i use the links